# Regular Expression For Extracting Province from Canadian Address?

Tags: regex

The source I'm getting addresses from is inconsistent, it comes in 3 different ways

100 rue des Commandeurs Lévis Québec Canada

100 rue des Commandeurs Lévis Québec G6V7N5 Canada

100 rue des Commandeurs Lévis Québec G6V 7N5 Canada

The First address and street part are always going to be different lengths. "Canada" provides a good anchor for finding the province but the challenge is the postal code is sometimes broken into 2, sometimes combined, and sometimes not there.

I have a solution but I'm looking for a better one. My solution was to extract the first three terms before Canada.

```
RegExExtract Address (\S+)\h(\S+)\h(\S+)\h+Canada
```

And analyze each phrase to see if it had a digit.

```
RegExtract Phrase 1 (\d)  
   If RegEx Fails, Phrase 1 = Territory  
   If Success, RegExtract Phrase 2 (\d)  
       If RegEx Fails, Phrase 2 = Territory  
       If Success, RegExract Phrase 3 (\d)  
           If RegEx Fails, Phrase 3 = Territory    
           If Success, "Something went wrong"
```

This works fine but I assume there's a better way.

Comment: How about "British Columbia", "Nova Scotia" or "Newfoundland and Labrador" though? I would think that since there are only 10 provinces, your best bet is to not use regex, or just hardcode all of the province names in the regex pattern with alternation.

Comment: That's fine I can just use an array and some more regex later on to turn Labrador into Newfoundland and Labrador, Columbia to British Columbia etc. Basically the equivalent of a Vlookup in excel.

Correct me If I'm wrong but I think the problem with your proposal is there's going to be roads and streets named after different provinces in each province. I.e. there might be an Ontario St. in British Columbia.

Comment: That's another problem that I considered and a great point. Combining the two approaches or matching all and taking the last one before "Canada" could help solve it, but the point is that the problem is non-trivial and I think the scope of the possible text cases could be embellished further to avoid presumptuous answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
(?i)(\S+)\h*(?:G[A-Z0-9]+\h?[A-Z0-9]+)?\h+Canada
```

might be somewhat close, yet maybe a better option would be to simply list those States in a capturing or non-capturing group, such as with:

```
(?i)(Québec|Ontario|British Columbia|Montreal|Victoria|Saskatchewan|Calgary|Newfoundland|Nova Scotia|Alberta)(?:\h+)?(G[A-Z0-9]+)?(?:\h+)?([A-Z0-9]+)?\h+Canada$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eef0G8/1/)